# running time of jobs in aws batch

Tags: amazon-web-services, jobs

i want to find the total time of all the jobs which has been executed in aws batch. how can i find that?
I know how to find the start time and end time of a job but actually I want to find the performance of AWS batch so I need to find running time of all the aws batch jobs which executes in a day.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like AWS Batch doesn't export the metrics on e.g., job running duration to CloudWatch.

One way to get such daily performance indicator is to use CloudWatch Log Insights,

1. Log starting time and finishing time for your jobs running in AWS batch
2. Perform a Log Insights SQL query, grouping by day and apply e.g., aggregations of average

This way the daily performance of AWS Batch jobs can be analyzed programatically.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find it directly too.
The closest solution for me was, using the CloudWatch log insights query with the below script.

```
 fields @timestamp, @message
| filter @logStream LIKE /BatchJobName/ and (@message LIKE /FINISHED EXECUTION_DATE/ OR @message LIKE /STARTING EXECUTION_DATE/)
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 200
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).